# How to replace special characters in ansible

Tags: ansible

I'd like to ask, how to replace special characters in ansible.
When I print out the stdout in ansible  Ihave escaped characters, which I want to remove from the output.
e.g.

```
\e[0m
```

I tried `replace('\\e[0m', '')`, but it did not work.. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

UPDATE:

```
    - name: Running the docker image 
      command: docker run "{{ image_name }}"
      register: result

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ result.stdout_lines  | replace('\\e[0m'', '')| replace('\\t', '') }}"
      when: result.stdout_lines is defined
```

but output is still:

```
"\e[1mTEST1 \e[0m\e[0;32m[OK]\e[0m"
```

sh generates colors and formats:

```
BOLD='\033[1m'
RED='\033[0;31m'
GREEN='\033[0;32m'
BLUE='\033[0;34m'
YELLOW='\033[0;33m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color
```

So, somehow `\033` results in `\e`

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code that is producing those characters?

Comment: Can you show us an example playbook? It might help if we knew what is producing the escape sequences.

Comment: ...great minds think alike...

Comment: @Nick updated, \\t is replaced but \\e... is not working

Comment: The code is produced by sh script, then the output is"\e[1mTEST1                                                         \e[0m\e[0;32m[OK]\e[0m"

Comment: What is output by ```result.stdout```? Does the script output these characters directly? Are you using the ```command``` or the ```shell``` module?

Comment: the output is registered in a module , which runs first:it runs docker image (the entry point is a sh script, which produces the output). I use   register: result, see above, I have added the module which is running the image

Comment: @Nick the thing is, that sh script outputs the formatted text, colored and etc. I'd like to save it, while I am printing it out in ansible, but I did not figure out, so at least I'd like the output to be clean without any escaped characters, so it is readable.

Comment: In your ```ansible.cfg``` file that is getting imported, what are the values for force_color and nocolor in the [defaults section](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-configuration-settings-locations). Try setting nocolor to true and forcecolor to false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two main problems: result.stdout_lines is an array, not a string; and the output you see is probably not the same as goes through the replace filter.

To solve this, you should force what you're sending through replace to be a string.  Either of these should do that though the second only operates on the first element.

```
    msg: "{{ ''.join(result.stdout_lines)  | replace('\\e[0m', '')| replace('\\t', '') }}"
```

```
    msg: "{{ result.stdout_lines[0]  | replace('\\e[0m', '')| replace('\\t', '') }}"
```

you could also use the map filter as shown here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html with replace.

I'd suggest using the first form if all you want is to simply get the output without certain text.  If you're going to reuse this pattern frequently, I'd suggest figuring out map+regex_replace.

Comment: Great answer.  I'll just add, you could use "result.stdout" in place of "''.join(result.stdout_lines)" or "result.stdout_lines[0]"